# Updating the user ranking with a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two tables, one contains user data and the other contains user ranking information (points needed for the promotion)

Let's say that the user table looks like this:

```
login | ArticlePoints | PhotoPoints | StageId
```

and the user ranking information table looks like this:

```
StageId | StageName | MinimumPoints
```

and the user information table might contain data like this:

```
1 | Beginner | 100
2 | Advanced | 200
3 | Expert   | 300
```

What I would like to have is a procedure which does add user points and check whether it is enough for the ranking promotion. Right now I do it like this:

1. I do have a function which does check "manually" whether the user points is between 100 and 200 and then it does set the user stage = 2, id it's more it check whether it's between 200 and 300 etc.
2. Stored procedure which does `update users set stage = MYFUNCTION from the point 1`.

The thing is that it's not a good solution, right now it is not ready for the easy updates(I can't just add Super Expert with minimum 400 points, I'd need to edit the function).

I am trying to prepare a better solution for this problem but I have no idea how to "connect" both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an `UPDATE` query that returns the `StageID` for the calculated values, something like:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.StageID = 
        (SELECT TOP 1 StageID 
         FROM [RANKING_TABLE] t2 
         WHERE t1.ArticlePoints + t1.PhotoPoints >= t2.MinimumPoints 
         ORDER BY t2.MinimumPoints DESC)
FROM [USER_TABLE] t1
```

So if the USER has 250 points in total, Beginner and Advanced would be achieved, using the `TOP 1` and the `ORDER BY t2.MinimumPoints DESC`, would select the highest Stage.

Comment: Thanks, generally it does the job but for some reason it does not want to accept the **[USER_TABLE] t1** it says that the **t1** shouldn't be there and it asks for the **SET**. Because of this the inner select doesn't select proper values(if I remove t1). I didn't think that my solution was such an overkill

Comment: Try that, I have modified the query to put the alias correctly in the FROM clause, my mistake